# AWS EMR encrypt S3 bucket using KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-kms

I have the below situation for my EMR, can someone please guide how to go about to configure the same?

EMR Cluster performs multiple operations across the data pipeline:

1. EMR write to `S3BUCKET1` with `KMSKEY1`
2. EMR write to `S3BUCKET2` with `KMSKEY2`

How do I configure the above in EMR? Only options I am aware to config EMR is at `emrfs-site.xml` & `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/core-site.xml`

These have the tags `fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId`

How do I achieve my requirement with above KMS keys? I need to switch between KMS keys for different bucket write.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach encrypt/decrypt permission to EMR_EC2_DefaultRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": [
            ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Specify you keys in resources and attach it to the role.